# Azure DevOps - enumerating and setting project permissions for default built-in groups with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, devops

I want to read and modify membership of default groups for Azure DevOps project permissions, like "Contributors" or "Project Administrators" with PowerShell (modules).

Thanks a lot!

Whatever I tried, there is one little piece missing to accomplish the tasks:

a) Is there a way to use **REST APIs** to dump those default-groups and not only the Team groups, like described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP
I am able to successfully read Teams, but I'm still failing in reading the built-in groups...
Can't also find any Microsoft docs which helps in this case...?

b) I found this PS Module (**VSTeam**):
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VSTeam/7.15.2
Great Module, Bearer-Token auth. included, ... But failed in fulfilling my specific task. Maybe I missed something...?

c) I found another PS Module (**PSDevOps**):
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSDevOps/0.5.9
Dumping built-in groups works with this module, but I can't figure out any way to set group memberships as well. Another smaller issue: Only PAT support implemented.

d) **az devops CLI**:
This extension can be used to list project and groups and the like (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops).
While there is nothing wrong in using this extension, it works similar like the native REST API with security descriptors (based on REST methods) and needs logic and creates another dependency in using az CLI commands.

Did anyone stumble over the exact same challenge :-)? Any ideas?

It doesn't matter if using the REST API or a Module, my requirements are:

1. authentication should be done with a Bearer-Token, I want to avoid using a PAT.
2. because I'm using those scripts in Pipelines I want as few dependencies as possible to Modules, CLI extensions, ... --> preferably don't leave the PowerShell object experience
3. it would help if the security descriptor evaluation/exploding logic must not be implemented, instead is handled by any module/cli extension

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **`Azure Devops CLI`** commands to list and ***update membership of the default groups***, You are not required to use **`PAT token`**, You can directly use `az login` and run the `az devops` commands:-

***Commands:-***

```bash
az login
az devops security group list  --output table
az devops security group list
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Command to update the membership:-***

*Replace group-id with descriptor from above commands output:-*

```bash
az devops security group membership add --group-id vssgp.xxxxxxxLTAtMC0wLTAtMQ --member-id sidxxxx@gmail.com --output table
```

**Output:-**

[image]

References:-
[MS Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/manage-tokens-namespaces?view=azure-devops#update-permissions), [MS Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/namespace-reference?view=azure-devops#internal-namespaces-and-permissions)

***Commands to update the permissions of the group, Add the group descriptor ID to the subject parameter:-***

```bash
az devops security permission update --allow-bit 8 --id 112xxxxxxx307204ce4 --subject vssgp.Uy0xLTkxxxxxxzU3NDQxMDc2LTEyMDQzNxxxxyMjM4MS0xxxxxxxTAtMQ --token $/3b344e43-98b7-4dc6-89b7-cdd8b56ece1f --output table
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) Rest API to update the memberships of the Azure DevOps groups.